# how to get urllib2 to return data as an array

Tags: python, json, string, list, urllib2

Not sure if this is even possible, but if so it would be awesome.

My code is:

```
url = "https://*myDomain*.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/*{id}*/tags.json"
req = urllib2.request(url)
password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, url, 'example@domain.com', 'password')
auth_manager = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_manager)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
tagsA = response.read()
print tagsA
```

Now the data that is returned is:

```
{"tags":[]}
```

The API call itself returns the following

```
{
tags: []
}
```

However trying to access the list doesn't work as it seems to treat tagsA as a string. I would like it to treat it as a list so that I could check if 'tags' is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to load json string into python dictionary via [json.loads()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

...

tagsA = json.loads(response.read())
print tagsA['tags']
```

Or, pass `response` to [json.load()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) (thanks to @J.F. Sebastian's comment):

```
tagsA = json.load(response)
print tagsA['tags']
```

Comment: or `json.load(response)`. Both assume that the character encoding is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

You need to `json.load` (or `json.loads`) the response body.

However, if you're going to do any kind of semi-complicated HTTP calls (authentication, cookies, etc.) in Python, you should really be using Kenneth Reitz's excellent Requests library (http://python-requests.org/) instead of urllib calls. Your entire code would become:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url, auth=("my_username", "my_password"))
tagsA = response.json()
```